# Basic Notification System in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, notifications, social-networking

I have a small scale PHP social network, running with a MySQL database. Users on the network can join various groups and receive updates.

I want to notify the user when a new update has been released by a group.

I don't want to do anything fancy with sockets, I'd just like a display of how many updates have been posted since the user was last active.

I'd thought of recording the current time against a user every time they refresh the page, this way I can compare the date of updates vs. the last time a user was active.

I'm not sure that writing to the database on every page load is a good idea though. Any other suitable suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to do this is indeed writing to the database. However, in terms of performance there are a few ways to make it faster. Two ways I can think of are caching the updates for popular groups and creating a table which will only have users and timestamps, both indexed, so that should work very quickly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you explain why using a separate table would be quicker than just extracting one column from the existing user table? Cheers.

Comment: I don't know whether the difference will actually be felt, but if the table is very large it would create unnecessary overhead, definitely if you use the same query to get other information.

Comment: Where is the extra overhead coming from? Surely both tables will have the same number of rows and can be indexed on the same fields.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is fine. Make sure you index the correct fields in your database.

Now if you *ever* have a question like this again.. go through the following steps:

- Try it
- Measure

If you're worried about scalability problems down the road.. do the same thing again, except you measure with how many records you expect (or want to support). It will be easy to just generate 10.000 records or even millions and try again.

Now if you *actually* run into unacceptable speeds, write down your problem and ask again here how you could potentially optimize.

Comment: Yes Dad. I'd rather spend some time thinking about a clever solution than waste time testing loads of poor alternatives.

Comment: I'm saying that every database-based solution may cause a performance problem in certain situations. Only if you measure first you can determine if you have a problem, and explore (more complicated) alternatives.

Comment: You describe an extremely generic situation, so you cannot expect more than an extremely generic answer. (e.g.: you worry about a single-field where query?).